# Perform a login only with an Angular SPA with SSO identity server WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to login to WSO2 , using SSO but without a server, just using Angular.  Is that possible ?

Comment: If I understood correctly,  your requirement is that users should be able to signin/log in to an Angular SPA application by authenticating from the WSO2 Identity server ? Is it?

Comment: Yes, I want to use wso2 to login using angular SPA.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [asgardeo-auth-angular-sdk](https://github.com/asgardeo/asgardeo-auth-angular-sdk/blob/main/README.md) in your Angular application to use OIDC or OAuth2 authentication and connect to WSO2 IS for authentication.

Also, You can try out the same thing quickly in Asgardeo (cloud offering of WSO2 IS) by following the [sample Angular application](https://wso2.com/asgardeo/docs/sdks/).

Comment: I understand that there is such a possibility, but I will not use Asgardeo. I will use WSO2 installed on a server.

Comment: Yes, the SDK shared will work with the community version of Identity Server.

Comment: Doesn't work, as it has a bug that hasn't been released in npm.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug where there was a loop after login, that was fixed with:

```
 if (!SPAUtils.hasAuthSearchParamsInURL(this.navigator.getCurrentUrl())) {
     this.auth.signIn();
 }
```

However, the latest version of npm does not have such a fix implemented.

how can i use the latest version in an angular project then ?